# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.hasProperty

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs, tomcat10

I am trying to build api using ``` jersey ``jax-rs ``` , `maven` and i run it on `tomcat-v10`
Those are my files:

**Ressource.java**

```
package com.api;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("myresource")
public class Ressources {
    
    
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String sayHello(){
            return  "say Hello";
        }
    

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>api_java</groupId>
  <artifactId>api_java</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>api_java</name>
  <description>api java rest</description>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.1.0</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**This is the Error showed by tomcat**

[image: This is the Error showed by tomcat]

**Update: Solved**

I don't need the dependency. jakarta-plateform

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or if I add the attribute. `<scope>provided</scope>`
to this `dependency` the problem will be solved, also!

Comment: Can you post the results of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Double-checking: is the spelling of `jakarta.jakartaee-api` correct?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify. The problem here is that `SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel` extends `jakarta.ws.rs.core.Configuration` and `Configuration` is expected to have `hasProperty` implemented.

`hasProperty` is implemented in JavaEE10 and the fix here is to have that API on classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or just the artifact causing the problem:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```